How can I setup Google Drive for Mac to NEVER delete anything?
I would like to use Google Drive to back files up from my Mac, and I don't want to worry about deletions.
What I would like is for any file I create to be backed up.  If I delete it on my PC, I don't want it to be deleted in Google Drive.  If I delete it in Google Drive, I don't want it deleted off my PC.  I don't want anything to be deleted that I haven't explicitly commanded.
How can I setup my Google Drive backups to never delete anything unless I explicitly command it to?

At some point there was a way.  In typical Google fashion, their UI has changed old solutions no longer work.
https://support.google.com/drive/thread/13979848/any-way-for-back-up-and-sync-to-not-delete-a-synced-file-while-i-delete-it-myself-on-the-pc?hl=en.

The plot thickens.  They seem to have removed the feature? https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/q58c2z/option_to_never_remove_both_copies_was_in_backup/

I've asked the community here: https://support.google.com/drive/thread/268513226?hl=en&sjid=16034168631871899574-NC

From my research, it isn't possible.  I took about 3 hours to research how to backup a folder to the web, and the only service I could find that does backups and not just "syncing" is iDrive.  Hope that saves someone some time.
